# Maze Recursive Division algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, maze

I am currently making a random maze generator in Python that stores its values in a 2 dimensional array. This will be used in the future as a pathfinding algorithm tester for me.
I attemped to make this using the Recursive Division Algorithm, as it seemed the most intuitive to me.

I do not have experience with Python.

To allow for the most amount of combinations possible, I gave the user the option to choose the height and width, using

```py
def dimensions():
    height = int(input("Desired height: "))
    width = int(input("Desired width: "))

    res = (height, width)
    return res
```

As per the algorithm rules, I create an empty array surrounded with walls, and with a start and end point, given by:

```py
def create_array(height, width):
    maze = np.zeros((height, width), dtype = int)

    for i in range(height):
        maze[i][0] = 1
        maze[i][width - 1] = 1
    
    for i in range(width):
        maze[0][i] = 1
        maze[height - 1][i] = 1
        

    return maze

def set_start_end(start, height = 0, width = 0):
    if start == True:
        elems = [0,1]
        random.shuffle(elems)

    else:
        elems = [[height - 1, width - 2], [height - 2, width - 1]]
        elems = random.choice(elems)

    res = (elems[0], elems[1])

    return res
```

Both the start and end point are chosen from the upper-left, and lower-right corner, once again, to allow for more possible combinations.

Following this, I created 3 auxiliary functions:

```py
def choose_orientation(height, width):
    if width > height:
        return VERTICAL
    elif width < height:
        return HORIZONTAL
    else:
        return random.choice((VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL))

def set_wall(length):
    coor = int(length/2)

    if (coor % 2 != 0):
        coor += random.choice([-1, 1])
    
    return coor

def set_door(length):
    coor = random.randrange(1, length - 1)

    if (coor % 2 == 0):
        coor += random.choice([-1, 1])
    
    return coor
```

The first is pretty staightforward, it chooses the direction in which the wall will be created, based on the current height and width of the room.
The following two functions make sure that walls will only be created in even cells, and doors the oposite.

My main recursive loop is the following:

```py
def divide(maze, x, y, height, width, resolution):
    h = height
    w = width

    if w <= resolution or h <= resolution:
        return

    orientation = choose_orientation(h, w)

    w_coor = 0
    w_length = 0
    d_coor = 0
    
    if orientation == HORIZONTAL:
        w_coor = set_wall(w)
        d_coor = set_door(w)

        w_length = w

        for i in range(w_length):
            maze[x + w_coor][i] = 1
        
        maze[w_coor][d_coor] = 0
    
        for elem in [[y, w_coor - y + 1], [w_coor, y + h - w_coor - 1]]:
            divide(maze, x, elem[0], elem[1], w, resolution)

    else:
        w_coor = set_wall(h)
        d_coor = set_door(h)

        w_length = h
         
        for i in range(w_length):
            maze[i][y + w_coor] = 1
        
        maze[d_coor][w_coor] = 0

        for elem in [[x, w_coor - x + 1], [w_coor, x + w - w_coor - 1]]:
            divide(maze, elem[0], y, h, elem[1], resolution)
```

And yet, the result somehow always resembles the following:

```
[[1 5 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 1]]
```

I haven't been able to spot the problem, and don't know what else to do

As per @Stef's answer, I have switched the arguments given to `set_wall` and `set_door`, giving me a slightly better result

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [5 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: In `if orientation == HORIZONTAL`, I am guessing `w_coor = set_wall(w); d_coor = set_door(w)` should instead be `w_coor = set_wall(w); d_coor = set_door(h)`. And similarly in the `else`.

Comment: When you manage to fix your algorithm I suggest posting your code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as there are a lot of things that are technically correct, but could be written in a *subjectively better* way.